# Html Table data is returning "None"

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am working to scrape proxy addresses using selenium webdriver from this http://proxydb.net/?protocol=socks4&country=BD . But while trying to scrape data from table I'm getting "None" . Here is my code::

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(
    'http://proxydb.net/?protocol=socks4&country=BD')
String = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")
print(String.get_attribute('text'))
browser.quit()
```

Here is the output:

```
C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Hello World>python -u "c:\Users\Asus\Documents\Hello World\Web Scraping\proxy\proxy1.py"

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56478/devtools/browser/215c65c4-d3c5-4653-85c1-1f63ccde50ba
[36844:7508:0115/050206.852:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [05:02:06.852] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[36844:7508:0115/050206.854:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [05:02:06.854] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[36844:7508:0115/050206.870:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [05:02:06.869] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
None
```

Here, why am I getting this
`[36844:7508:0115/050206.852:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [05:02:06.852] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)` ?
and how to solve this "None" problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text of an element. First you wait for the element to load and then you print it's text.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser,10)
elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")))
print(elem.text)
```

Outputs

```
203.188.245.98:52837
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```